# Update Query issue for multiple rows

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have below update query to set some values and controle the data flow.But i am  getting error "Too many values" from the condtion(subquery)when i execute the bellow query.

```
UPDATE MTB       ----- TABLE NAME
SET MTB_EXTR_FLAG='N',
MTB_ALOC_PROCESS='DC1'
WHERE MTB_I IN      --- PRIMARY KEY
(
SELECT * FROM
(
SELECT MTB_I ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ROWID) AS RN
FROM MTB
)
WHERE RN BETWEEN 100 AND 500
)
```

Here my intension is selecting the different set up data per processing of one job.
I want to  set MTB_EXTR_FLAG='N',MTB_ALOC_PROCESS='DC1' each time before running of the job with different set of data.

Can someone please help me to resolve the error issue or propose different query.

Thank you.

Comment: I'ts not smart to order by rowid - The rowid can change when you perform different operations on the table. How do you rank your data if not by rowid ? i'm guessing you want to rank by the time the row was created. do you have a update_date column in the table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is just a matter of number of columns not matching (2 - `MTB_I` and `RN` - instead of 1 - `MTB_I`):

```
UPDATE MTB       
SET MTB_EXTR_FLAG='N',
MTB_ALOC_PROCESS='DC1'
WHERE MTB_I IN      --- PRIMARY KEY
(
SELECT MTB_I FROM -- Else RN will be taken !!
(
SELECT MTB_I ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ROWID) AS RN
FROM MTB
)
WHERE RN BETWEEN 100 AND 500
)
```

You can't do `where x in (...)` with a subquery returning more fields than expected.

Comment: Thank you Emmanuel .Now its working after rplacing the "select * " with "Select MTB_I"